# How can I get file path in str format from nested dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary (==Filesystem)) and I want to have output in the format of a file path example:
/bin/echo
/bin/mkdir
...
/lib/systemd/system/sudo.service

Is there any way please?

```
Filesystem =
{ "/" :[{ 'bin': ['echo', 
                   'mkdir', 
                   'ls', 
                   'ip', 
                   'kill'
                  ]
         },
         {'lib': [ { 'init': ['fstab',
                              'vars.sh',
                              'upstart-job'
                             ]
                    },
                    {'udev' : ['accelerometer',
                               'ata_id',
                               'cdrom_id'
                               ]
                    },
                    {'systemd': [  { 'system' : ['sudo.service',
                                                 'rsync.service',
                                                 'anacron.service'
                                                ]
                                   },
                                   { 'system-sleep':['notify-upower.sh'
                                                    ]
                                   },
                                   'systemd-logind',
                                   'systemd-udevd',
                                   'systemd-localed'
                                ]
                    }
                  ]
            },
           {'home' : [ { 'documents' :[ {'reports' : []},
                                         'ToDo.txt',
                                         'book.pdf',
                                         'results.pdf'
                                      ]
                      
                       },
                       {'music' : [ {'album1': ['song1.mp3', 
                                                'song2.mp3'
                                                ]
                                    },
                                   {'album2' : ['song1,mp3', 
                                                'song2.mp3'
                                               ]
                                   }
                                 ]
                       },
                       {'pictures' : [ {'holiday' : ['photo1.jpg',
                                                     'photo2.jpg',
                                                     'photo3.jpg',
                                                     'photo4.jpg'
                                                    ]
                                       },
                                       {'trip' :  ['photo1.jpg',
                                                   'photo2.jpg',
                                                   'photo3.jpg',
                                                   'photo4.jpg'
                                                  ]
                                       }
                                    ]
                      }
                    ]
          }
        ]
            
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a recursive function to traverse the dicts/lists is the easiest way:

```
def traverse_fs_dict(fs):
    if isinstance(fs, str):
        return [fs]
    if isinstance(fs, list):
        return [e for f in fs for e in traverse_fs_dict(f)]
    assert isinstance(fs, dict)
    return [
        ('' if root == '/' else root) + '/' + path
        for root, child in fs.items()
        for path in traverse_fs_dict(child)
    ]
```

For your `Filesystem` input this produces:

```
/bin/echo
/bin/mkdir
/bin/ls
/bin/ip
/bin/kill
/lib/init/fstab
/lib/init/vars.sh
/lib/init/upstart-job
/lib/udev/accelerometer
/lib/udev/ata_id
/lib/udev/cdrom_id
/lib/systemd/system/sudo.service
/lib/systemd/system/rsync.service
/lib/systemd/system/anacron.service
/lib/systemd/system-sleep/notify-upower.sh
/lib/systemd/systemd-logind
/lib/systemd/systemd-udevd
/lib/systemd/systemd-localed
/home/documents/ToDo.txt
/home/documents/book.pdf
/home/documents/results.pdf
/home/music/album1/song1.mp3
/home/music/album1/song2.mp3
/home/music/album2/song1,mp3
/home/music/album2/song2.mp3
/home/pictures/holiday/photo1.jpg
/home/pictures/holiday/photo2.jpg
/home/pictures/holiday/photo3.jpg
/home/pictures/holiday/photo4.jpg
/home/pictures/trip/photo1.jpg
/home/pictures/trip/photo2.jpg
/home/pictures/trip/photo3.jpg
/home/pictures/trip/photo4.jpg
```