# How do I print out a nested dictionary in a file path format?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a function that returns a nested dictionary, which contains file path names.

For example`{'/': {'home': {'documents': {}}}}`

I want it to be printed out as `/home/documents/`

How can I do this? I know how to print out keys from a normal dictionary, but I can't figure out how to do this to a nested dictionary.

This nested dictionary can vary in size as well, so I'd like the printing function to work no matter the size of the nested dictionary

This is all in Python

Comment: Recursive solution is the way to go. Have you written anything?

Comment: check out this solution
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64613575/how-can-i-get-file-path-in-str-format-from-nested-dictionary